# iPhone: updated info.plist value not being read

Tags: iphone, plist

I have an app that when first launched reads in its data from a local XML file and is then archived for subsequent loads.

In future app updates its envisioned that this XML file might be updated with more data. To determine if I should re-load the XML data I have placed a custom key/value (a version number for the XML file) in the info.plist.

Now when I update the version number from 1.0 to 1.1 in the plist file, the app still reads it as 1.0. I'm guessing there is some kind of caching going on. Is there a way I can get the updated version on each load?

```
NSDictionary* infoDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString* version = [infoDict objectForKey:@"IdeasVersionNumber"];
NSLog(@"version = %@",version); // always 1.0?!!
```

Is there a better method to do this? I didn't want to create a separate plist/XML file just to hold the version number as it seems like a waste of resources to load/parse these each time when the info.plist is always read.

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: have you tried doing a clean build?

Comment: thanks, that did it @MCannon, if you post it as an answer I'll mark it as correct so you get the rep points :)

Comment: have you tried doing a clean build?

Comment: hi @MCannon sorry for delay in responding. Yes a clean build did the trick. thanks for your input. If you add it as an answer I will mark it as the correct one and give you the points for your troubles. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple clean build did the trick! Thanks to @MCannon for the tip. I should have copped onto it.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised by this behavior, but as it looks like the Info.plist is *not* always read, you might as well make a separate file for it. Or use NSUserDefaults.